# How to save data entered in text input in flatlist render item react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, textinput

There are 2 textinputs in `Flatlist` render and how can I save the text entered in 2 text inputs when I click save button.
How can I handle `onChangeText` in flatlist render.

```js
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:['0','1'],
      textInputs: [],
    }
  }

<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={this._render.bind(this)}
  extraData={this.state}
  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
/>

_render({ item, index }){
  return (
    <View style={{ width: width / 1.3, marginTop: 20, padding: 20, borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: 'black' }}>
      <TextInput
        ref={input => { this.textInput = input }}
        placeholder={'First Name'}
        placeholderTextColor={'grey'}
        style={{ height: width / 12, width: width / 1.5, textAlign: 'center', borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
        onChangeText={(text, index) => this.onChange(text, index, item)}
      />
      <TextInput
        ref={input => { this.textInput = input }}
        placeholder={'Last Name'}
        placeholderTextColor={'grey'}
        style={{ height: width / 12, width: width / 1.5, textAlign: 'center', borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, marginTop: 10 }}
        onChangeText={(text, index) => this.onChange(text, index, item)}
        value={this.state.textInputs[index]}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { this.saveItem(index) }}>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 10 }}>
          SAVE
      </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

[image]

**For example, if I click save on 1st render item I should get the first name and last name entered in inputs of 1st render item. if I click save on 2st render item I should get the first name and last name entered in inputs of 2nd render item.**

Comment: Hi, so for us to be able to help you. We would need some more information regarding what you mean when you say save. If what you are aiming at is long time saving you would have to set up a database containing the 2 fields and then with the help of the javascript Fetch API save it. Alternatively using some kind of file system server side. If what you are aiming at doing is saving the item locally within the app. You could define your save function to be something in style with. 

saveItem = (txt1, tx2) => {
    this.setState({ data : [...data, { some json containing the data }];
}

Comment: not saving, for now, I want to get and print the text entered in text fields based on render item individually.
For example, 
if I click save on 1st render item I should get the first name and last name entered in inputs of 1st render item.
if I click save on 2st render item I should get the first name and last name entered in inputs of 2nd render item.